# Zooming the webpage distorts the layout of my webpage

Tags: html, css

When we normally zoom in or zoom out a webpage (by pressing Ctrl + or Ctrl -) the entire page components remain together like the following screenshot of this page

[image]

But when I zoom my webpage instead of zooming to a specific area ,the components get distorted

[image]

Here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Are you ready for the show?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="home.php">
            <img src="../images/logo.png"></img>
            <span id="logo_name">Dooms Day</span>
        </a>
        <span id="login">
            LogIn
        </span> 
    </div>
</dody>
</html>
```

and  the css

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body
{
    font-family:Palatino,Georgio,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
}

#header
{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(50,51,47);
    height:80px;
}

#header a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
}
#logo_name
{
    font-size:25px;
}
#header img
{
    padding-top:12px;
    margin-left:10%;
}

#login
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:8px 20px 8px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(100,192,0);
    margin-left: 60%;
    border-radius: 10px
}
```

What should I do to achieve this effect as its necessary for symmetry?

Comment: Use `@media` tags. Use relative layout. Try making your pages responsive.

Comment: @Ranveer:Can you please elaborate what you mean by "responsive"?

Comment: Check out http://getbootstrap.com/. Try playing with the browser size. The elements adjust, whatever the browser size may be. This is called responsiveness. Bootstrap is an awesome high-end responsive framework used extensively nowadays.

Comment: This responsiveness can be easily achieved by the above mentioned properties: `@media` tags and relative layouts.